# typescript function signature conflict

Tags: typescript, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

On my ionic/webstorm app I am using a cordova plugin (specifically dialogs) and typescript.  However, I am using the ngcordova wrapper - which not only does not have typescript typings, but whose function signature differs from the cordova function - so I am getting the typescript red squiqqlies (sp?).  Unfortunately at this time getting rid of ngcordova is not an option.  What is the easiest way to solve this - make a copy of the cordova Dialogs.d.ts and change the signature?

Answer (score 0):

> make a copy of the cordova Dialogs.d.ts and change the signature

No. Most likely *the signatures are different for a reason and this is a valid case where TypeScript is actually helping you preventing you from making an error at runtime*. If you disagree with the compiler, you can always assert to `any` and the compiler will get of your case

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: The ngcordova function wrapper hides a parameter the cordova function never uses; in other words it is strictly for convenience.  Thanks for the link; can I tell the ts compiler to ignore not just a type but a function?  I suspect this ability (or something like it) must be available for working with 3rd party js libraries.